# What is the exact difference between "/" and "%" in the expr command?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to know the difference between "/" and "%"!

When I type and run the following command I get 0:

```
expr 4 % 4
```

But when I run same command and replace "%" with "/" I get 1

```
expr 4 / 4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man expr`

> ARG1 % ARG2
>
> arithmetic remainder of ARG1 divided by ARG2

`4 % 4` evaluates to `0` as that is the remainder

> ARG1 / ARG2
>
> arithmetic quotient of ARG1 divided by ARG2

`4 / 4` evaluates to `1` as that is the ratio of these two numbers

Answer (score 2):

[expr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html) shall evaluate an expression and write the result to standard output.

`%` is [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator, `/` perform [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29) operator.

- `4 % 4` evaluated to `0`
- `4 / 4` evaluated to `1`